# Rewriting simple C# nested class

Tags: f#

What would be an elegant way to implement the functionality of this nested class in F#?

```
  private class Aliaser {
     private int _count;
     internal Aliaser() { }
     internal string GetNextAlias() {
        return "t" + (_count++).ToString();
     }
  }
```

This was my first attempt, but it feels like there should be a sexy one-liner for this:

```
let aliases = (Seq.initInfinite (sprintf "t%d")).GetEnumerator()

let getNextAlias() = 
    aliases.MoveNext() |> ignore
    aliases.Current
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The usual way of writing is to create a function with local state captured in a closure:

```
let getNextAlias = 
  let count = ref 0
  (fun () -> 
     count := !count + 1; 
     sprintf "t%d" (!count))
```

The type of `getNextAlias` is simply `unit -> string` and when you call it repeatedly, it returns strings "t1", "t2", ... This relies on mutable state, but the mutable state is hidden from the user.

Regarding whether you can do this without mutable state - the simple answer is NO, because when you call a purely functional function with the same parameter twice, it must return the same result. Thus, you'd have to write something with the following structure:

```
let alias, state1 = getNextAlias state0
printf "first alias %s" alias
let alias, state2 = getNextAlias state1
printf "second alias %s" alias
// ...
```

As you can see, you'd need to keep some state and maintain it through the whole code. In F#, the standard way of dealing with this is to use mutable state. In Haskell, you could use *State monad*, which allows you to hide the passing of the state. Using the implementation [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595673/state-monad-why-not-a-tuple), you could write something like:

```
let getNextAlias = state { 
  let! n = getState
  do! setState (n + 1)
  return sprintf "t%d" n }

let program =
  state { 
    let! alias1 = getNextAlias()
    let! alias2 = getNextAlias() 
    // ...
  }

execute progam 0 // execute with initial state
```

This is quite similar to other computations such as `lazy` or `seq`, actually - computations in the `state { .. }` block have some state and you can execute them by providing initial value of the state. However, unless you have good reasons for requiring purely functional solution, I'd prefer the first version for practical F# programming.

Comment: That's helpful. Do you see any way to do this without declaring mutable state?

Comment: One thing I might add: you can use `incr count` instead of `count := !count + 1`

Comment: I realize there has to be mutable state _somewhere_, but I like for it to be hidden in a predefined pattern (e.g., lazy, seq).

Comment: @Daniel: Added solution using _state monad_ in the latest update :-).

Answer (score 2):

Here is the quick and dirty translation

```
type Aliaser () =
  let mutable _count = 0
  member x.GetNextAlias() = 
    let value = _count.ToString()
    _count <- _count + 1
    "t" + value
```

A more functional approach without state is to use continuations.

```
let createAliaser callWithValue = 
    let rec inner count = 
        let value = "t" + (count.ToString())
        callWithValue value (fun () -> inner (count + 1))
    inner 1
```

This is a declaration which will call the function `callWithValue` with both the value and the function to execute to repeat with the next value.

And here's an example using it

```
let main () =
    let inner value (next : unit -> unit )=  
        printfn "Value: %s" value
        let input = System.Console.ReadLine()
        if input <> "quit" then next()
    createAliaser inner     

main()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping for some functional succinctness.

Comment: Now that's cool. I still haven't gotten past the elusiveness of CPS.

Comment: @Daniel, CPS still makes my head spin on occasion.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `Seq.unfold : (('a -> ('b * 'a) option) -> 'a -> seq<'b>)` to generate the aliases.

Implemented as:

```
let alias = 
    Seq.unfold (fun count -> Some(sprintf "t%i" count, count+1)) 0
```

Comment: This won't maintain state between calls unless you implement something similar to my original post.

Comment: True, but I would use the generated sequence as state.